# If $x \varpropto z$ and $y \varpropto z$, prove that $x^2-y^2 \varpropto z^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $x \varpropto z$ and $y \varpropto z$, prove that $x^2-y^2 \varpropto z^2$

$\Rightarrow x=m_1z$ and $y=m_2z$

$\Rightarrow m_1^2z^2-m_2^2z^2=m_1^2z^2$ or $m_1^2z^2-m_2^2z^2=m_2^2z^2$

$\Rightarrow m_2^2z^2=0$ or $m_1^2=2m_2^2$

I'm stuck now and this result doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x,y \propto z$, then we have constants $a,b$ with $x=az,y=bz$.

Then $x^2 - y^2 = a^2 z^2 - b^2 z^2 = (a^2 - b^2) z^2$.

Of course, $a^2 - b^2$ is just another constant, so $x^2 - y^2 \propto z^2$.

The key realization from your work is that the constant of proportionality need not be the same as for $x$ or $y$.

Comment: So if I were to say $x^2-y^2 \varpropto z^2 \Rightarrow x^2-y^2 = cz^2$, then $(a^2-b^2)z^2 = c^2z^2$ This would also be correct? And then can I say $(a^2-b^2)=c^2$?

Comment: Sure, you could do that

Comment: Side note: Sometimes directly proportional requires $k\neq 0 $, in which case this statement need not be true.